# Get name and value of url params

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some url like this

```
/posts/singlepost?page=99
```

I need to get key and value of query in url and to put in new array, that i can loop,and use that key and value in my http request. In url **page** can be something else, i dont know what can be

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: which framework you talking about nodejs or client side javascript?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I prefer typescript, but it can be vanila javascipt, as i said i need to get params key and value and put in new array

Comment: Tried in Angular, but i had no luck

Comment: My question @daniel is not the sam, in my question i dont know name of keys?

Comment: @MiomirDancevic it is. look at URLSearchParams. There's plenty of information in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
// Get params.
const params = Array.from(new URLSearchParams(location.search))

// Add a loop.
params.forEach(([key, value]) => /* key is 'page' and value is 99 */)
```

Comment: This does not work

Comment: Even because URLSearchParams is deprecated

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Angular. The `URLSearchParams` used there is, as you said, deprecated in favour of `HttpParams`: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams. However what I have in mind is the standard `URLSearchParams` available globally: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` by `?` and then `split()` the second element by `=`

```js
let str = '/posts/singlepost?page=99';
let res = str.split('?')[1].split('=');
console.log(res)
```